# WordPress wildcard subfolders

Tags: php, wordpress, mod-rewrite, multisite, mod-alias

I need to make some subfolders aliases of main website. For example, I need that website.com/section1/ and website.com/section2/ act as website.com. I will use these folder as sections (regions) but the content will be the same for 80% of the site but will be sometime filtered by the section. I would prefer not to use multisite, I just want to categorize some data (pages, posts, custom posts) using these sections. If you visit website.com, you can choose which section you want and then navigate through website.com/section1/the-url-here.

Is it something possible?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use any of the Geo location Wordpress plugins like GeoPosty or SWG Location Aware it could be a solution that could save you loads of time

Comment: These regions are not actual regions, it is more a group of cities. I cannot use any Geo plugins. Thanks